# APEX LOV Display value look up

Tags: oracle-apex

Is it possible to reference a LOV in plsql?

I need to get the display value from a static LOV from PLSQL to use as a filter on an interactive report.

I have trawled the documentation and google but there is no reference to being able to reference a LOV via plsql.

Any help gratefully received

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the **value** of an item that has a LOV - that's usually what you want:

```
select ename from emp
where deptno = :p1_deptno -- P1_DEPTNO is a page item based on an LOV
```

For static LOVs you can access the display value like this:

```
select display_value
from apex_application_lov_entries
where application_id = 123
and list_of_values_name = 'DEPT_LOV'
and return_value = :p1_deptno;
```

For dynamic LOVs you would have to run the query the LOV is based on.  This can be obtained from view `apex_application_lovs`

Comment: The problem is that I am attempting to programatically filter an interactive report using apex_util.ir_filter, for this I need to pass in the value that is shown within the table rather than the id. The idea behind this is that I want to just display a subset of the records in the report without changing the sql behind the report and the user can then edit the filter if they wish to.  I was hoping it would act like an enum.